# Analyze text() node and add new nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm doing a html to xml conversion using XSLT, in html input I have content like follows,

```
<p>An image outside a paragraph is placed into an <em>Element Image Frame</em>. If there are no (or not enough) <em>Element Image Frames</em> then the image is ignored and a warning is logged.</p>
```

using xsl, what I need is, if there are space before or after `<em>` node, those nodes should be replaced by, `<space/>` node. so the expected output,

```
<p>An image outside a paragraph is placed into an<space/><Italic>Element Image Frame</Italic>. If there are no (or not enough)<space/><Italic>Element Image Frames</Italic><space/>then the image is ignored and a warning is logged.</p>
```

Note that there is no space after the first `<em>` node, so there is no `<space/>` added.

I think I can use XSLT regular expression, but I'm struggling to write a regular expression with select two spaces before and after `<em>` node.

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^(&#x20;)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(1)">
                        <space/>
                    </xsl:when>                
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone suggest me a method to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the condition can be checked with `starts-with` and/or `ends-with` but also involves the presence of a certain sibling element I would simply write templates with match patterns:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="em">
  <Italics>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </Italics>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()[starts-with(., ' ') and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::em]]">
   <space/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()[ends-with(., ' ') and following-sibling::node()[1][self::em]]">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length() - 1)"/>
   <space/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()[starts-with(., ' ') and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::em] and
                              ends-with(., ' ') and following-sibling::node()[1][self::em]]" priority="5">
   <space/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2, string-length() - 1)"/>
   <space/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct selector for whitespaces is `([\s\t]+)$` which says at least one whitespace (space or tab) at the end should be matched and can then be replaced. I didn't have the resource to test it with your specific code, though.